# Mongoose pre hook: pull _id from array on remove

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schema:

**Skills:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var SkillSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    skill: { type: String },
    tally: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    associatedUsers: { type: Array },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Skills", SkillSchema);
```

**Profile:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    username: String,
    password: String,
    skills: { type: Array }
    }
);

profileSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Profile", profileSchema);
```

The `Skills` document holds skills that are associated with various `users` (`Skills. Skills.associatedUsers`):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cab5c8788368eafb68b75a4"),
    "skill" : "cooking",
    "__v" : 0,
    "associatedUsers" : [
        ObjectId("5cab5c7d88368eafb68b75a0"),
        ObjectId("5cab546a7fb2b3a71c0404fa")
    ],
    "tally" : 0
}
```

And the `Profile` document contains an array of skills:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cab546a7fb2b3a71c0404fa"),
    "skills" : [
        "cooking", "cleaning"
    ],
    "__v" : 0,
    "username" : "deleteMe"
}
```

I am trying to implement a pre-hook in the `Profile` schema so that when a user is deleted, any instance of `user._id` in `Skills.associatedUsers` is also deleted.

I have tried the following, but it actually removes the entire entry for that skill:

```
const Skills = require("./skills");


profileSchema.pre('remove', async function(){
    console.log("clearing user ID from skills model");
    await Skills.remove({associatedUsers: { $in: this._id } });

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Profile", profileSchema);
```

**How can I `pull` the `._id` of the to-be-deleted user from the `associatedUsers` array in the `Skills` document?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `update` with [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/index.html) operator and specify `multi: true` to remove that value from all documents in `profile` collection:

```
profileSchema.pre('remove', async function(){
    console.log("clearing user ID from skills model");
    await Skills.update({}, { $pull: { associatedUsers: { $in: this._id } } }, { multi: true });
});
```